# XamarinFormsImageGallery with images from file

Tags: image, xamarin.forms

I'm using this component https://github.com/rasmuschristensen/XamarinFormsImageGallery to take a picture with camera and display it.

I have a problem when I want to show images from file, they don't show. Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I understood the problem. When at the beginning I'm loading in the view model all data and the control can't show anything because it doesn't recognise changes.

Then I bind the view model and then the data.